# Unable to send bulk request to Elasticsearch cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I am trying to send bulk request to Elasticsearch cloud with following curl string -

`curl -u myusername:mypassword -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST https://el.kb.us-east-2.aws.elastic-cloud.com/products/_bulk --data-binary "products-bulk.json"`

I am getting the following error -
`{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}`

Can someone please help me with the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong URL, you're using the Kibana URL while you should be using the ES one

```
https://el.kb.us-east-2.aws.elastic-cloud.com
           ^^
           ||
```

Should be

```
https://el.es.us-east-2.aws.elastic-cloud.com
           ^^
           ||
```

Comment: Elastic's copy endpoint feature is creating the issue. Thanks